# Applying Master Method on $ T\left( n \right) \ =\ n^{\frac{2^i-1}{2^i}}T\left( n^{\frac{1}{2^i}} \right) +in $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$$T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n})+n$$

Now, I found it it's after unrolling out equations:

$$ T\left( n \right) \ =\ n^{\frac{2^i-1}{2^i}}T\left( n^{\frac{1}{2^i}} \right) +in \tag{1}\label{1} $$

So, given that we have master method, which is $T(n) = a T(\frac nb) + f(n)$, where $f(n) = n^k\log{n}^p$, can we map \ref{1} to master method please? I found that this is indeed case 2 with $p=-1$ and $k=log_b(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled as follows

$$
\frac{T(n)}{n}=\frac{T(\sqrt n)}{\sqrt n} + 1
$$

or

$$
\mathcal{T}(n) = \mathcal{T}(\sqrt n) + 1
$$

so

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = \mathcal{T}(2^{\log_2\sqrt n}) + 1
$$

now calling $\mathbb{T}(\cdot) = \mathcal{T}\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{T}(z) = \mathbb{T}\left(\frac z2\right) + 1 
$$

or

$$
\mathbb{T}(2^{log_2 z}) = \mathbb{T}\left(2^{\log_2\frac z2}\right) + 1 
$$

Defining now $\Theta(\cdot) = \mathbb{T}(2^{(\cdot)})$ and $u = \log_2 z$ we follow with

$$
\Theta(u) = \Theta(u-1)+1
$$

with solution

$$
\Theta(u) = c_0 + u
$$

and now going backwards with $u = \log_2 z,\ \ z = \log_2 n$ we obtain

$$
T(n) = n\left(\log_2(\log_2 n)+ c_0\right)
$$

Comment: You answers are very clear. Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you assume please to have $
\mathcal{T}(n) = \mathcal{T}(\sqrt n) + 1
$

Comment: $\mathcal{T}(n) = \frac{T(n)}{n}$

Comment: Thanks. as $\frac{(T(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not same as $\frac{T(n)}{n}$, so how $\mathcal{T}$ can be substituted for both?.

Comment: Mind that $\mathcal{T}(\sqrt{n}) = \frac{T(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Also, where did $n$ came from in the last equation please $T(n) = n(loglog(n) + c_0)$ as I see we should have $T(n) = (loglog(n) + c_0)$, what do you think please?

Comment: We found $\mathcal{T}(n) = \log_2(\log_2 n)+ c_0$ then....

Comment: Thank you. I see now $\mathcal{T} = \frac{T(n)}{n} = log_2(log_2n)+c_0$, we multiply both sides by $n$ to get $T(n) = nloglogn  + nc_0$.